# snowflake convert string to timestamp

Tags: datetime, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a timestamp string value from source data which I wanted to convert into required format. Any idea on converting the string into timestamp is much appreciated.

```
String value of source data
'Fri Oct 16 03:27:06 PDT 2020'

I want above string to be converted into 
YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS

which should be like from the sample string shared
2020-10-16 03:27:06

As of now trying with below, but this sounds like not a good practice to have.

select to_timestamp(substr('Fri Oct 16 03:27:06 PDT 2020',5,15)||' '||substr('Fri Oct 16 03:27:06 PDT 2020',25),'MON DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY');
```

Any help to achieve the desired output would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After converting it to timezone, you can show it in any format:

```
select to_varchar(  to_timestamp( 'Fri Oct 16 03:27:06 PDT 2020', 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY') , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ;
```

Clean version:

```
SELECT to_varchar( column1, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
FROM VALUES (to_timestamp( 'Fri Oct 16 03:27:06 PDT 2020', 'DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY'));
```

Comment: Great thanks Gokhan.. Exactly what I'm looking for.. I just used below and got the desired result "select to_timestamp('Fri Oct 16 03:43:33 PDT 2020','DY MON DD HH24:MI:SS TZD YYYY');"

Comment: If this answer helps you, please take a moment to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from "greyed out" to "filled in".

Comment: To add to Gokhan's answer, there's been a recent update to Snowflake's TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP function that allows it to accept an optional format string. The benefit of TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP over TO_TIMESTAMP is that if the conversion fails it returns NULL instead of generating a SQL error -- if that's the behavior you'd prefer.